# MVC3 TextBoxFor with encoded text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-encode

Is there a way to use TextBoxFor helper with encoded text?

for example:
When using the following helper of MVC3 With Razor view engine :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Description)
```

and the value of model.Description is encoded, for example:

```
 &lt;script&gt;alert();&#39;&lt;/script&gt;
```

the result is text box with the the encoded string, 
when the wanted result is text box with the decoded string:

```
 <script>alert();'</script>
```

Is there a way to use the MVC TextBoxFor with encoded string instead of using

```
@Html.TextBox("Description", Server.HtmlDecode(Model.Description))
```

?

Comment: It looks to me like you might be over-encoding things somewhere. Why is the content encoded in the database? In general, it should *not* be: you should encode when displaying, in cases where you are protecting against injection. Encoding as you save and decoding when editing is fraught with errors and complications.

Comment: I thing that you are right, but it is good to know in cases that the data is saved to the database encoded. i'm guessing that the other method with @html.TextBox is the best solution for now.

Answer (score 5):

You have to html-decode your string.

Use the `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` for that.

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&lt;script&gt;alert();&#39;&lt;/script&gt;")
```

will result in

```
<script>alert();'</script>
```

TextBoxFor does not support that so, you have 2 options

**1. Decode before display**

```
    @{
        Model.Description = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.Description);
     }
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Description)
```

**2. Use @Html.TextBox for this**

```
    @Html.TextBox("Description", System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.Description))
```

**hope this helps**

Comment: Thank for the reply but the two option are not much different of what i suggested, probebly the closest solution for now.