# ASP.NET MVC3 - Display accented string in TextBoxFor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, non-ascii-characters, html.textboxfor

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC3 project.

In a basic update page, I'm trying to display data recorded in the DB into some `TextBoxFor`. However, the data can contain some special characters, like quote `'` or accented letters like `é`

When I write

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyProperty)
```

The displayed text looks like `L&#39;av&#233;e` instead of `L'avée`.

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402230/mvc3-textboxfor-with-encoded-text) but the answer doesn't change anything for me.

Is there a way to display my string **PROPERLY** with accented letters and quotes in a `TextBoxFor` ?

**UPDATE**

This field is in a partial view containing only this field :

```
@model MyApp.Models.SomeModel

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MyModel.Submodel.MyProperty)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyModel.Submodel.MyProperty, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtMyProperty" })*@
</div>
```

Here, `SomeModel` is correctly displayed (believe me).

- `SomeModel` has a `MyModel` property.
- `MyModel` has a `SomeModel` property
- `SomeModel` has a `MyField` field.

Everything is correctly filled from DB (believe me, it has been tested and re-tested).
However, I can't correctly display `MyField` if it has special characters. It is displayed, but with HTML reprensentation like `&#39;`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246439/asp-mvc-razor-encode-special-characters-in-input-placeholder

Comment: I already see this answer, but I can't do @Html.TextBoxFor(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(m => m.MyProperty))

Comment: what is wrong with the 1st option in here?http://stackoverflow.com/a/8402310/2436549

Comment: The problem is the field is still displayed as L&#39;av&#233;e. However when I put a breakpoint on it, the string is correct and contains my accented letters. But when the page is displayed, the field contains the HTML characters, which is not good.

Comment: I made a test application and provided my source below. It works perfectly. Upvodting Zsfars comment as it is correct. There is perhaps more information that we are not aware of...but with the information provided it answers the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC3 TextBoxFor with encoded text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402230/mvc3-textboxfor-with-encoded-text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link he provided in the comments is the correct answer.

```
@Html.TextBox("test", HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.MyProperty))
```

works correctly.

**My view**

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.SomeModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "title";
}
<h2>title</h2>
@{ Html.RenderPartial("Partial"); }
```

**My Partial View**

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.SomeModel

<div class="form-group">
     @{
         Model.MyProperty = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.MyProperty);
     }
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MyProperty)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyProperty, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtMyProperty" })
</div>
```

**My controller**

```
   public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            SomeModel model = new SomeModel
                {
                    MyProperty = "L&#39;av&#233;e"
                };
            return View(model);
        }


    }
```

Comment: In my case, I have a NullReferenceException on the `@Html.TextBox` line because Model is null. This field is in a partial view strongly typed with `@model MyModel` on line 1, can it be a problem ?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your full code. But if the partial view does not have a populated model then with or without encoding your data should not display.

Comment: The model is correctly populated, it works perfectly except if this field has accented characters. If it hasn't, the data is correctly displayed. The code populating this model is basic, I just get my DB object and fill my model with it. I'll investigate deeper because the problem must come from my app

Comment: Update your bug with the view code as you are stating it is populating a partial view.

Comment: can you also include your controller and parts of the view that call the partial

Comment: Sorry you were rigth, your solution is OK, I had a problem with JS executed after partial is loaded. I accept your answer. Thank you for your time !

Comment: You are most welcome. I updated my answer to match your code as well. I am not sure what the *@ at the end was for but that was causing me issues as well. Good luck.